# First Time Setup Taking Forever to Launch/Install

Tags: windows, performance, windows-server-2008, speed, setup

To start off, I am running a Windows Server 2008 32-bit computer, 8 GB ram (well supposedly only 4 GB would be used).  This computer is fairly new, and it is extremely fast in running applications and browsing the internet.  My problem is that launching a setup in the first place is taking a substantial amount of time.  For instance, I could try launching the setup for the Java JDK 7u6, but from the time I launch the setup, it took the computer more than a half hour to start up the setup.  The computer, during that 30 minute interval, still runs very smoothly (no difference at all actually), but it is just that the setup launches later than it should be.  By the way, it is a half an hour if I am lucky. I have had applications such as Microsoft Office 2010 Trial take multiple hours for it to start to launch. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Do you have antivirus installed? If so, disable it and see if that helps.

Comment: @RandolphWest I read about that but I don't have any antivirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have antivirus you can do following

1. if problem is particularly for JDK setup(other setups are running fine) please check 
   prerequisites and installation procedure.
2. try to close as many applications as possible before launching setup
3. try to **Run as administrator**(Right click and click run as administrator);
   check How much time it takes to show UAC dialogue.
4. try to boot computer in **safe mode** and try to install. if in safe mode its running smoothly 
   may be the problem with some of some installed applications or drivers.
5. Check **event viewer**-->Windows-->Applications log. (To run type eventvwr in run and 
   press enter) if it helps to identify the problem.
6. if still problem is not identified launch task manager and check if the process for
   setup(msiexec or setup.exe)is started. if its started the setup is started but maybe 
   due to some resource or script issue its not proceeding to UI.

Hope this helps..

Comment: This question doesn't really apply to me anymore since I am done with my internship at my workplace, but thank you for answering the question! Hopefully, this might help someone else with a similar problem.